Replace wrong values in a dataframe using a dataframe of correct values
In my DATA below, some Names are misspelled. I've determined the Unique_Names and correspondingly created the Correct_Unique_Names for those unique names.
But I wonder how to insert my Correct_Unique_Names in DATA to achieve my Desired_output below?
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- read.table(header=T,text=
"Name      
Asan
Ziba       
Asan       
Asana
Farhan
Frahan
Zibaee
Ziba")

Unique_Names <- unique(DATA) %>% 
arrange()

Correct_Unique_Names <- 
  read.table(header=T,text=
"Name
 Aasan
 Zibae
 Aasan
 Farahani
 Frahani
 Zibae")

Desired_output <- read.table(header=T, text=
  "
Name      
Aasan
Zibae      
Asan       
Aasan
Farhani
Farhani
Zibae
Zibae")


Here I would create a translation table with wrong names in one and correct names in another column. Then make a database join and replace the misspelled values. Another method is to use fuzzy matching.

You have some errors in your data. I'm assuming that I have fixed them correctly. The following code should work:
DATA |>
  left_join(data.frame(Unique_Names, Correct_Unique_Names),
            by="Name") |>
  select(Name.1) |>
  rename(Name=Name.1)

     Name
1   Aasan
2   Zibae
3   Aasan
4   Aasan
5 Farhani
6 Farhani
7   Zibae
8   Zibae


library(dplyr)
